# Sorting a list string paths in jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to sort an array of file paths but it seems to not do its job.

```
def files = findFiles(glob: "**/vars/*.txt")
files = files.sort()
echo "Found the following documentation files: ${files}"
```

The `.sort()` or `.sort(false)` does not have an effect on the list containting something like `[vars/test.txt, vars/tmp.txt, ...]`

How do sort this a list with path within a jenkins pipeline?

Comment: What is the type of the objects kept on `files`?

Comment: https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/ seem to be array of strings.

Comment: I saw it. It's definitely not, since `String` does not have `name`, `path` or `directory` fields. Try `files.sort { it.path }`.

Comment: @Opal using the `it.path` results in `Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.ArrayList$Itr`

Comment: Try to replace `path` with `name` and `println` the type of elements - it will be much easier to help.

Comment: Ah.. `it` may refer to something else so it might be: `files.sort { f -> f.path }` - could you please try it?

Comment: @Opal still the same error. The object returned of `findFiles` is of type https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/fs/FileWrapper.java

Comment: Yes, I've already checked that. No idea then, sorry. `FileWrapper` is `Serializable`.

Comment: Thanks anyways! Seem to be a bit odd that the sorting does not work out at all.

Comment: This worked for me - https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wololock/a77ab13bf64a1ab27257022e3cef8449/raw/3f0db9758d5b21560dcca8849cb5c927d660f858/Jenkinsfile Jenkins 2.60.3 with org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.8

Comment: You could be running into [JENKINS-44924](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44924) with `.sort {}`

Comment: @mkobit yes. Looks pretty much like my issue. I tried every combination from assigning it to use the mutating variant and it simply stays the same. Thanks for the issue reference!